# Notepad++, How to lock EOL conversion?

Tags: notepad++

I can go to `Edit > EOL conversion` and choose the desired one, but not all other files have this.

How could I lock it to ensure it will be the default EOL conversion for all files whatever? Or at least, for all files from a given language?

Comment: Please what do you mean by "not all files have this"? And what N++ version you are using?

Comment: I'm talking on all files whatsoever because I usually work with Unix files and I really don't care that a few Windows files will have Unix EOL. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Using EditorConfig plugin:

Your requirement could be probably achieved using [EditorConfig N++ plugin](http://editorconfig.org/) which supports end-of-line settings like

```
# Unix-style newlines with a newline ending every file
[*]
end_of_line = lf
insert_final_newline = true
```

The setting on 3rd line should do what you expect. Check the above hypelink to learn more.

The plugin is available for automatic download and installation through N++ menu **Plugins** > **Plugin Manager**.

#### Without plugins:

Please do not expect your requested functionality from Notepad++ core (without plugins) because what you expect is *automatic conversion* of line endings when file is open in Notepad++. But N++ *preserves* content of files instead of automatically changing it without user notice. If it was doing automatic changes, someone would expect automatic change of encoding when file is open, someone automatic change of tabs/spaces, someone change of indentation... This would lead nowhere.

The easiest way without plugins is to open **Settings** > **Shortcut Mapper** and in section **Main** find command **Convert to UNIX format** and assign that command a keyboard shortcut. Then you can have your conversion made on pressing a hotkey.